# Metapost how can you return values in a recursive function?

Tags: programming, metapost, metafont, programming-tools

I am trying to code the recursive definition of B splines but I am stuck writing the recursion, my code won't compile because I am trying to assign "vacuous to numeric",

According to online resources, to return a value you need to omit the semi colon at the end.

However this doesn't compile:

```
vardef calculate_basis(expr t, i, order)= 
    numeric ret;
    if order=0:
        index := knots[i];
        if (t >= index) and (t < knots[i+1]):
            label.top(textext("\huge$"& decimal(70) &"$"), (0,0));
            ret := 1
        else:
            ret := 0
        fi;
    else:
        (t-knots[i]) / (knots[i] + order - knots[i]) * calculate_basis(t, i, order-1) + (knots[i + order + 1] - t) / (knots[i + order + 1] - knots[i+1] * calculate_basis(t, i+1, order-1))
    fi;
    ret := 0
enddef;

% Start figure
beginfig(0);

make_knots(3, 7);

val = calculate_basis(0.5, 1, 0);
endfig;
```

But changing the last line to `calculate_basis(0.5, 1, 0);`, i.e eliminating the assignment, does run without issues.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `ret` at the end of your `vardef` macro, so that it takes the value of the `ret` variable:

```
vardef calculate_basis(expr t, i, order)= 
    numeric ret;
    if order=0:
        index := knots[i];
        if (t >= index) and (t < knots[i+1]):
            label.top(textext("\huge$"& decimal(70) &"$"), (0,0));
            ret := 1
        else:
            ret := 0
        fi;
    else:
        (t-knots[i]) / (knots[i] + order - knots[i]) * calculate_basis(t, i, order-1) + (knots[i + order + 1] - t) / (knots[i + order + 1] - knots[i+1] * calculate_basis(t, i+1, order-1))
    fi;
    ret := 0;
    ret % new line here!
enddef;
```